# No results for taxonomy archive page

Tags: query, taxonomy, terms

So, I'm making a taxonomy template page for a plugin, but I'm not getting any results from my query.

I'm loading the template with this.

```
function projects_categories( $taxonomy_template ) {
  if( is_tax( 'ppw_projects_categories' ) ) {
    $taxonomy_template = PPW_PLUGIN_DIR . 'includes/views/taxonomy-ppw_projects_categories.php';
  }
  return $taxonomy_template;
}
add_filter( 'taxonomy_template', 'projects_categories' );
```

This works fine I can see the template when I go to the term link

This is the query.

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$projects_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'       => 'post_type',
  'tax_query'       => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
      'field'    => 'slug',
      'terms'    => $term->slug,
    ),
  ),
  'order'           => 'ASC',
  'paged'           => $paged
));
if( $projects_query->have_posts() ) :
  while( $projects_query->have_posts() ) : 
    $projects_query->the_post();
    // stuff 
  endwhile;
endif; wp_reset_postdata();
```

I am getting no results when I try to query for the specific taxonomy term. I even tried hand coding the taxonomy and term in the 'tax_query' parameter in case something is going wrong with get_query_var(). Still with no results.

Comment: Don't use a custom query, use the main query with the default loop, thats all. :-)

Comment: Tried that, too with no results, but I do need to use a custom query.

Comment: Use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter the main query. var dump `$wp_query->request` to see the SQL query being generated.

Comment: Var Dump: string(388) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (11) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'projects' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10"

Comment: that looks fine to me. do you have projects assigned to that taxonomy term?

Comment: Yes, I even use the term link to pull up the page

Comment: Why do you need to run a custom query?